# AngularJS http.jsonp request .then and .success functions not work

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, jsonp

My client app is an angularJS application. The server is built by Laravel 5.

In the client, I conduct a jsonp CORS request :

```
$http.jsonp("http://server.com/api?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
```

In the laravel server, a json data is returned :

```
return Response()->json($query);
```

However, when I try

```
$http.jsonp("http://server.com/api?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
.then(function(response){
    alert('success');
});
```

or

```
$http.jsonp("http://server.com/api?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
.success(function(response){
    alert('success');
});
```

Both status are `200 OK`. But no alerts will appear. And I try

```
$http.jsonp("http://server.com/api?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
.then(function(response){
    alert('success');
},function(error){
    alert('fail');
});
```

The result is a status of `200 OK` but the alert is "**fail**"! How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular's `$http.jsonp` converts the request querystring parameter from `callback=JSON_CALLBACK` to `callback=angular.callbacks._0`.

In the controller in Laravel, you need add the prefix into your response string.

```
return $request->input('callback')."(".$query.")";
```

Then, the angular application will confirm this response and pass to the `.then` or `.success` function.

Answer (score 1):

JSONP requires callback function "JSON_CALLBACK" on server side. Alternatively, you can make use of proxy. http://www.whateverorigin.org/